# RewriteRule webroot to file-system path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Have checked out lots of topics here and there regarding the issue in question,
but no results yet.

So here is the issue.

Two projects:

- proj: site.loc
- proj2.0: newsite.loc

They are located in different places on the file system.
And i need to redirect from one project to another internally,
so url for site.loc is preserved.
E.g. requesting site.loc/hey/there i need apache to serve files form proj2.0.

First, i know that on the .htaccess level we cannot use RewriteRule to file-system path
(for security reasons).
Okay, an Alias is a workaround.

Say i add an Alias to virtual host as following:

```
Alias /newsite /some/path/to/proj2.0
```

Then if i'll add the rule to proj's .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^hey/there /newsite
```

This will work.

But, the webroot does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /newsite
```

Is it i'm doing something wrong or there is some quirk about the webroot ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not rewrite to your root, but suppress it. Here is how I have done it in my project to suppress the www

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

There should be a way to make it work with your /newsite in the same manner.

Comment: not really clear what do you mean ?
i tried this and it does not work:
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$ [NC]`
    `RewriteRule ^ /newsite [L]`